# Getting LARGE nested Json from NYT API

Tags: android, json, api

I'm trying to use the New york times api to show the headline and an image in a listview on android. I'm already getting the data for headline and date and outputting to log cat. The real problem is: whenever I put the extra field to get the mulimedia (images url) the  "GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1902K (64), 22% free 11931K/15156K" is shown

I've seen that the api always sends fixed number of 10 nyt articles, but each of the 10 has a multiple multimedia urls and json with arrays nested and the app freezes. I'll learn to put the data on listview on my own, my real question is, whats the best approach to fix the crash, I only want 1 url image per article.

//THE RETURNED JSON WITH ONLY "MULTIMEDIA" FIELD QUERY.

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2018 The New York Times Company. All Rights 
   Reserved.",
  "response": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "multimedia": [
          {
            "rank": 0,
            "subtype": "xlarge",
            "caption": null,
            "credit": null,
            "type": "image",
            "url": "images/2018/09/07/opinion/07Parcak/merlin_143215881_20cecc31-7c8d-4b8f-8541-773170c1822c-articleLarge.jpg",
            "height": 400,
//MORE CODE HERE.. THEN NEXT ARRAY BELOW
  {
    "multimedia": [
      {
        "rank": 0,
        "subtype": "xlarge",
        "caption": null,
        "credit": null,
        "type": "image",
        "url": "images/2018/09/03/world/03xp-brazil-promo/03xp-brazil-promo-articleLarge.jpg",
        "height": 400,
        "width": 600,
        "legacy": {
          "xlarge": "images/2018/09/03/world/03xp-brazil-promo/03xp-brazil-promo-articleLarge.jpg",
          "xlargewidth": 600,
          "xlargeheight": 400
        },
        "subType": "xlarge",
        "crop_name": "articleLarge"
      },
      // Goes on forever.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you use to get the data, what kind of REST client are you using?

For example if you are parsing the response by yourself you can put some logic like

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("multimedia");
JSONObject firstMultimedia = null;
if (arr.length() > 0){
firstMultimedia = arr.getJSONObject(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm using AsyncTask with  try/atch. result string  then:
 `{
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            Log.i("resultprint",result);
            return result;
 `

Comment: I notice when I get less then the 10 articles, and find only 1 article with a few url images, it logs to logcat. :/

Comment: Please check this tutorial I am sure you will find it useful
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/